# JQuery replace CC number except for last four digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a div that I need to strip away all characters except for the last four. I'm currently using replaceWith for this, but it replaces the whole thing.

Here's what I have

```
<div class="field-name-field-credit-card">1111111111111111</div>

$(".field-name-field-credit-card").replaceWith("xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx");
```

and my result

```
<div class="field-name-field-credit-card">xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx</div>
```

But I would like it to be:

```
<div class="field-name-field-credit-card">xxxx xxxx xxxx 1111</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCKfB/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I made a regex for you and updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCKfB/15/):

```
$( ".field-name-field-credit-card" ).text(function(_,val) {
    return val.replace(/\d{12}(\d{4})/, "xxxx xxxx xxxx $1");
});
```

but I have to agree with [Niet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982721/507674) - ***don't mask the credit card client side***.

If you really do want to mask client side, this ugly line of code will do it.

What it does is replace the text of the current element with the text it currently has, run through a regex with `replace`.  The regex looks for 12 digits, then stores the next 4, and replaces the string of 16 digits with the 'x's followed by those last 4 it saved.

Comment: I've just noticed that the jQuery in this is bad, because you're using `.field-name-field-credit-card`, a class name, as though it were a unique ID. This code will run into problems if you happen to try doing two credit card fields. It would be much better as `$(".field-name-field-credit-card").text(function(_,txt) {return txt.replace(/.*(\d{4})$/,"xxxx xxxx xxxx $1");});` (whitespace added, of course) as this will handle any number of fields correctly. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

Comment: Thanks for the fix, @NiettheDarkAbsol.  Yours is much more robust.

Comment: There's at least one perfectly non-bad reason to do this in javascript. If one is displaying, say, an order confirmation as the last step in a single-page checkout wizard, and the cc number (which has just been entered in a form field on the client side) hasn't yet been sent to the server, then showing a masked cc number via javascript is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Many of the order confirmations I've seen that run off of client-side data show the whole credit card number as part of the confirmation. It's when you store it on the server that it comes back masked.  There's a case for what you describe, but you should consider if the mask or the opportunity to confirm the number one last time before submitting it is more important to your user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like you might be passing the CC# from the server to the client via plain text, which is *not good*, I can think of why masking the CC on the client side is a good idea, so here goes:

You're at work ordering a gift online for a friend or loved one, maybe because you want it to be a surprise, and this is the safest place to do that. You get to the check out screen and your boss comes up behind you to ask if you got the memo about the TPS reports. Now, you've already finished entering your info and you're just about to hit submit when this happens and so there's your CC info. All of it. Just sitting there for anyone to see. It's not hidden in the source code somewhere or being passed in plain text over the network -- you're on SS-fucking-L or whatever. You don't know, you just know it's secure.

Luckily the web page coder people put in a little magic to mask your CC info when you tab out of the input. Here's what they might have done:

```
var maskValue = function(){
CCInput.data('value', CCInput.val());
if (CCInput.val().length > 4) {
    CCInput.val(new Array(CCInput.val().toString().length-3).join('•')+CCInput.data('value').substr(-4)); // change all but the last 4 digits to *
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n32jmqar/

Added an unmask function in case your dear user might wanna make sure they got everything right first. ;)